# Add jars to maven from external server and regularly update them

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have java webstart application and I need to use application API for testing purposes.
For this I need jars which are located on webserver (e.g.  `http://webserver/webstart/core.jar`) and this jars should be **always** up to date (building performed 4 times a day)
Is it possible, using Maven, to add this jars to the project and update them automatically before running tests? I was googling for solution but didn't find exact answer. I find that I can add external jar from local computer, also find that I can add some repositories but in fact I'm not strong in Maven:(

```
<repository>
    <id>some.api</id>
    <name>some API</name>
    <url>http://webserver/webstart/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled> 
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Comment: @Maksym could you please explain, why it's not a maven task?

Comment: You should consider some **scheduler** for that , e.g. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1